# Python Selenium if element is none click other element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, if-statement

Every time I access a page for a different stock on the same website one of the buttons that needs to be clicked either has this xpath `"//*[@id="content"]/div[1]/div/a[4]"` or this xpath `"//*[@id="content"]/div[1]/div/a[5]"`.

If the first xpath doesn't match the stock selected, how can I make it switch to the other xpath, whilst simultaneously not getting a NoneType error?

One of my attempts:

```
tradebut=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[1]/div/a[4]')
        tradebut.click()
        if tradebut.click() == None:
            browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[1]/div/a[5]').click()
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You can use the l or sign in the xpath to seperate two types and then use a try except to catch the error. This clicks if one of the xpaths work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your actual error is something like `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'click'`, you can handle the exception like this:

```
try:
    tradebut = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[1]/div/a[4]')
    tradebut.click()
except AttributeError:
    tradebut = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[1]')
    tradebut.click()
```

If the error is different, swap `AttributeError` with yours or just remove it leaving only `except:`.